# Call to a member function extension() on null Laravel 8

Tags: php, validation, file-upload, laravel-8

[image]

I having this problem when trying to enter data.
even though for the field in question in the database I have set it to be null.
but form and laravel system still consider it can't be null.
what is the solution for this, ?

My controller (BeritaController) with insert method :

```
public function insert()
    {
        Request()->validate(
            [
                'judul' => 'required|min:8|max:100',
                'penulis' => 'required',
                'keterangan' => 'required',
                'sampul' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,mp4|max:100000',
                'sampul1' => 'nullable',
                'sampul1' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,mp4|max:100000',
                'sampul2' => 'nullable',
                'sampul2' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,mp4|max:100000',
                'sampul3' => 'nullable',
                'sampul3' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,mp4|max:100000',
                'sampul4' => 'nullable',
                'sampul4' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,mp4|max:100000',
                'sampul5' => 'nullable',
                'sampul5' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,mp4|max:100000',
                'sampul6' => 'nullable',
                'sampul6' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,mp4|max:100000',
                'sampul7' => 'nullable',
                'sampul7' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,mp4|max:100000',
                'sampul8' => 'nullable',
                'sampul8' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,mp4|max:100000',
                'sampul9' => 'nullable',
                'sampul9' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,mp4|max:100000'
            ],
            [
                'judul.required' => 'Judul Wajib di Isi !!',
                'judul.max' => 'Judul Maximal 100 Karakter',
                'judul.min' => 'Judul Minimal 8 Karakter',
                'penulis.required' => 'Penulis Wajib di Isi',
                'keterangan.required' => 'Keterangan Wajib di Isi',
                'sampul.required' => 'Sampul Wajib di Upload',
                'sampul.mimes' => 'Extension File Harus .jpg, .jpeg, .bmp, .png, atau .mp4',
                'sampul.max' => 'Maximal ukuran file 100 MB',
                'sampul1.mimes' => 'Extension File Harus .jpg, .jpeg, .bmp, .png, atau .mp4',
                'sampul1.max' => 'Maximal ukuran file 100 MB',
                'sampul2.mimes' => 'Extension File Harus .jpg, .jpeg, .bmp, .png, atau .mp4',
                'sampul2.max' => 'Maximal ukuran file 100 MB',
                'sampul3.mimes' => 'Extension File Harus .jpg, .jpeg, .bmp, .png, atau .mp4',
                'sampul3.max' => 'Maximal ukuran file 100 MB',
                'sampul4.mimes' => 'Extension File Harus .jpg, .jpeg, .bmp, .png, atau .mp4',
                'sampul4.max' => 'Maximal ukuran file 100 MB',
                'sampul5.mimes' => 'Extension File Harus .jpg, .jpeg, .bmp, .png, atau .mp4',
                'sampul5.max' => 'Maximal ukuran file 100 MB',
                'sampul6.mimes' => 'Extension File Harus .jpg, .jpeg, .bmp, .png, atau .mp4',
                'sampul6.max' => 'Maximal ukuran file 100 MB',
                'sampul7.mimes' => 'Extension File Harus .jpg, .jpeg, .bmp, .png, atau .mp4',
                'sampul7.max' => 'Maximal ukuran file 100 MB',
                'sampul8.mimes' => 'Extension File Harus .jpg, .jpeg, .bmp, .png, atau .mp4',
                'sampul8.max' => 'Maximal ukuran file 100 MB',
                'sampul9.mimes' => 'Extension File Harus .jpg, .jpeg, .bmp, .png, atau .mp4',
                'sampul9.max' => 'Maximal ukuran file 100 MB',
            ]
        );


        //jika validasi tidak ada maka simpan data
        //upload gambar/foto
        $file = Request()->sampul;
        $fileName = Request()->judul . '.' . $file->extension(); //rename nama berdasarkan judul 
        $file->move(public_path('foto_berita'), $fileName);

        $file1 = Request()->sampul1;
        $fileName1 = Request()->slug1 . '.' . $file1->extension(); //rename nama berdasarkan judul 
        $file1->move(public_path('foto_berita'), $fileName1);

        $file2 = Request()->sampul2;
        $fileName2 = Request()->slug2 . '.' . $file2->extension(); //rename nama berdasarkan judul 
        $file2->move(public_path('foto_berita'), $fileName2);

        $file3 = Request()->sampul3;
        $fileName3 = Request()->slug3 . '.' . $file3->extension(); //rename nama berdasarkan judul 
        $file3->move(public_path('foto_berita'), $fileName3);

        $file4 = Request()->sampul4;
        $fileName4 = Request()->slug4 . '.' . $file4->extension(); //rename nama berdasarkan judul 
        $file4->move(public_path('foto_berita'), $fileName4);

        $file5 = Request()->sampul5;
        $fileName5 = Request()->slug5 . '.' . $file5->extension(); //rename nama berdasarkan judul 
        $file5->move(public_path('foto_berita'), $fileName5);

        $file6 = Request()->sampul6;
        $fileName6 = Request()->slug6 . '.' . $file6->extension(); //rename nama berdasarkan judul 
        $file6->move(public_path('foto_berita'), $fileName6);

        $file7 = Request()->sampul7;
        $fileName7 = Request()->slug7 . '.' . $file7->extension(); //rename nama berdasarkan judul 
        $file7->move(public_path('foto_berita'), $fileName7);

        $file8 = Request()->sampul8;
        $fileName8 = Request()->slug8 . '.' . $file8->extension(); //rename nama berdasarkan judul 
        $file8->move(public_path('foto_berita'), $fileName8);

        $file9 = Request()->sampul9;
        $fileName9 = Request()->slug9 . '.' . $file9->extension(); //rename nama berdasarkan judul 
        $file9->move(public_path('foto_berita'), $fileName9);
        $data = [
            'judul' => Request()->judul,
            'penulis' => Request()->penulis,
            'keterangan' => Request()->keterangan,
            'created_at' => Request()->created_at,
            'updated_at' => Request()->updated_at,
            'sampul' => $fileName,
            'slug1' => Request()->slug1,
            'sampul1' => $fileName1,
            'slug2' => Request()->slug2,
            'sampul2' => $fileName2,
            'slug3' => Request()->slug3,
            'sampul3' => $fileName3,
            'slug4' => Request()->slug4,
            'sampul4' => $fileName4,
            'slug5' => Request()->slug5,
            'sampul5' => $fileName5,
            'slug6' => Request()->slug6,
            'sampul6' => $fileName6,
            'slug7' => Request()->slug7,
            'sampul7' => $fileName7,
            'slug8' => Request()->slug8,
            'sampul8' => $fileName8,
            'slug9' => Request()->slug9,
            'sampul9' => $fileName9,
        ];

        $this->BeritaModel->addData($data);
        return redirect()->route('berita')->with('pesan', 'Data Berhasil Di Tambahkan !!!');
    }
```

I've also tried adding nullable validation but it doesn't work.